# An error in SQL syntax when saving data record into the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, struts

I have an error in SQL syntax when saving data record into the database:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option, createdBy, createdDate, updatedBy, updatedDate, description) values ('QU' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 86 more
```

In Get Session Method `getSession`

**Struts code:**

```
public T saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        try {
            getSessionTx().save(entity);
            commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            getSession().close();
        }
        return entity;
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<appendText.size();i++){
        PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 playerPredictionOptionLevel2 = new PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2();
        playerPredictionOptionLevel2.setPlayerPredictionLevel2Id(str);
        playerPredictionOptionLevel2.setOption(appendText.get(i));
        getDaoFactory().getPlayerPredictionOptionLevel2Dao().saveOrUpdate(playerPredi‌​ctionOptionLevel2);
    }
```

**Hibernate:**

```
insert into expert_predictor.player_prediction_option_level2 
    (player_prediction_level2_id, option, createdBy, createdDate, updatedBy, updatedDate, description) 
  values 
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Entity mapping:**

I have checked my entity with my DB but still there is an issue
and one thing this table have not any relationship using unique key I have managed all the code.
Please help me to solve this problem

```
package com.expertPredictor.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author CHiRAG
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_prediction_option_level2", catalog = "expert_predictor", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement

public class PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 implements Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "player_prediction_option_level2_ID")
    private Integer playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID;


    @Column(name = "player_prediction_level2_id")
    private String playerPredictionLevel2Id;

    @Column(name = "option")
    private String option;

    @Column(name = "createdBy")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updatedBy")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "updatedDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2() {
    }

    public PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2(Integer playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID) {
        this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID = playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID;
    }

    public PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2(Integer playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID, String playerPredictionLevel2Id, String option, String createdBy, Date createdDate, String updatedBy, Date updatedDate) {
        this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID = playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID;
        this.playerPredictionLevel2Id = playerPredictionLevel2Id;
        this.option = option;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public Integer getPlayerpredictionoptionlevel2ID() {
        return playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID;
    }

    public void setPlayerpredictionoptionlevel2ID(Integer playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID) {
        this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID = playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID;
    }

    public String getPlayerPredictionLevel2Id() {
        return playerPredictionLevel2Id;
    }

    public void setPlayerPredictionLevel2Id(String playerPredictionLevel2Id) {
        this.playerPredictionLevel2Id = playerPredictionLevel2Id;
    }

    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID != null ? playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2)) {
            return false;
        }
        PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 other = (PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2) object;
        if ((this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID == null && other.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID != null) || (this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID != null && !this.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID.equals(other.playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.expertPredictor.model.PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2[ playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID=" + playerpredictionoptionlevel2ID + " ]";
    }

    @Override
    public EntityStatus getStatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(EntityStatus status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not hibernate generate query, paste the sql query.

Comment: public T saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
  try {
   getSessionTx().save(entity);
   commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   rollback();
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   getSession().close();
  }
  return entity;
 }

Comment: and my struts code for save data

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < appendText.size(); i++) {
   PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 playerPredictionOptionLevel2=new PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2();
   
   playerPredictionOptionLevel2.setPlayerPredictionLevel2Id(str);
   playerPredictionOptionLevel2.setOption(appendText.get(i));
   
   
   
   getDaoFactory().getPlayerPredictionOptionLevel2Dao().saveOrUpdate(playerPredictionOptionLevel2);
  }

Comment: Don't put code here in comments, you can edit your question.

Comment: yes but i dont know how to use it bcoz first time i am using this system so pls help me

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem? i have do so much code in this structure but first time getting this error

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, Enable show_sql in config file and see what query it is generating.

Comment: also put the domain object code

Comment: i have put hibernate query u can see.

Comment: also put the PlayerPredictionOptionLevel2 code

Comment: you mean entity mapping?

Comment: yes, mapping and entity class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have SQL syntax error in the SQL generated by hibernate. The hibernate generates SQL according a dialect used by the configuration settings and it does it right, so there should not be errors if you have used HQL or criteria queries. If you are using MySQL JDBC driver then you are connecting to the MySQL database. HQL uses object mapping to get names for the tables and columns used by the query. If you are using `save` via hibernate session object then `insert` SQL statement is generated. The error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'option,** createdBy, createdDate, updatedBy, updatedDate, description) values ('QU' at line 1

shows you which column name is wrong. You can also check [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) from the MySQL Reference Manual.

Usually such names can be used in the SQL if they are backquoted. For example specifying a column name as `` `option` ``. But it's MySQL specific, and better rename it to something not reserved.